# Decrease space between rows with \cline?

Tags: tables, spacing, cline

I added \cline to a couple of columns of the table. However, that seems to be adding space to the entire row and it looks weird. How can i decrease it? (i tried using \vspace but it didnt work.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\catption{\textbf{Table A2:} XYZ }
\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{1.1cm}p{3cm}p{1.1cm}p{3cm}p{1.1cm}}

\hline\\
\textbf{[a] French LO}& \textbf{State}\\
\cline{1-2}

& & Mexico& 0.593& Japan& 0.884 \\
Albania& 0.572& Moldova& 0.377& Korea, Rep.& 0.915 \\
Algeria& 0.599& Morocco& 0.829& Latvia& 0.321 \\
Angola& 0.304& Mozambique& 0.231& Mongolia& 0.520 \\
Argentina& 0.245& Netherlands& 0.749& Poland& 0.593 \\
Armenia& 0.537& Niger& 0.406& Slovak Republic& 0.400 \\
Belgium& 0.741& Panama& 0.258& Slovenia& 0.505 \\
Benin& 0.192& Paraguay& 0.270& Switzerland& 0.810 \\

 \cline{5-6}
 Bolivia& 0.684& Peru& 0.632& 
 \textbf{[d] Scandinavian LO}& 
 \textbf{State}\\
 \cline{5-6}\\

 Brazil& 0.269& Portugal& 0.810& Denmark& 0.771 \\
Burkina Faso& 0.326& Romania& 0.462& Finland& 0.340 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use the rules from `booktabs`: the vertical spacing is far  too tight with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're using `\cline{x-y}\\` instead of just `\cline{x-y}`.

The horizontal line specifications (`\hline`, `\cline` or otherwise) are specified at the beginning of every line. Therefore, including an ending `\\` in their construction issues another empty line in the `tabular`.